# Magento2: How to add language switcher

Tags: magento2, switcher

Before I use one website and mutli language view:
[image]

then this language.phtml switcher work and display in heder:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Language switcher template
 */
?>
<?php if (count($block->getStores())>1): ?>
    <?php $id = $block->getIdModifier() ? '-' . $block->getIdModifier() : ''?>
    <div class="dropdown dropdown-switcher language switcher-language" id="switcher-language<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $id?>">
        <?php foreach ($block->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
            <?php if ($_lang->getId() == $block->getCurrentStoreId()): ?>
                <button class="switcher-toggle dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?>
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <?php foreach ($block->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
                <?php if ($_lang->getId() != $block->getCurrentStoreId()): ?>
                    <li class="view-<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getCode()); ?> switcher-option">
                        <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getTargetStorePostData($_lang); ?>'>
                            <img alt="<?php echo $_lang->getCode(); ?>" src="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png') ?>" /><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But now I changed and add mutli website for multi language (separate domains):
[image]

and now the language switcher has stopped displaying. Does anyone know how I can change it?

@Update3
I found file default.xml:

I changed this block from:

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header" after="-">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="currency" before="store_language" template="currency.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                        <arguments>
                                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">links</argument>
                            </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
```

TO:

```
    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Your\Custom\Block\Class" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="currency" before="store_language" template="currency.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
            <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">links</argument>
                </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

But still this issues on line 19:

```
<?php foreach ($websites as $website): ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Language switcher shows for multiple languages per website. It does not show if each website has only one language.

In this case, if you want to show switcher, you can show the website switcher.

Please try with the following code:

```
<?php $websites = $block->getAllWebsites();?>
<div class="switcher store switcher-store" id="switcher-store">
<strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?php echo __('Select Store') ?></span></strong>
<div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">
    <?php foreach ($websites as $website): ?>
    <?php if ($websiteid == $website->getId()): ?>
        <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger"
             role="button"
             tabindex="0"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
             data-toggle="dropdown"
             data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
             id="switcher-store-trigger">
            <strong>
                <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($website->getName()) ?></span>
            </strong>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown" data-target="dropdown">
        <?php foreach ($websites as $website): ?>
        <?php if (!($websiteid == $website->getId())): ?>
            <li class="switcher-option">
                <a href='<?php echo $website->getDefaultStore()->getCurrentUrl() ?>'>
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($website->getName()) ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Update:** As you are using the existing language.phtml file, you also need to create a custom block file and use it in the XML layout file for calling the PHTML file.

The code block file should be like below:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
) {
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function getWebsites() 
{
    $_websites = $this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
    return $_websites;
}
```

Now while calling the PHTML file from the layout XML, use the new block class.

**Update 2:** Location of layout XML file should be under **`app/design/frontend/{current-theme-package}/{{current-theme}}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`**

In this file you should see something like:

```
<block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml"/>
```

If yes, you need to change it to:

```
<block class="Your\Custom\Block\Class" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="Magento_Store::switch/languages.phtml"/>
```

Comment: Mohit I updated my topic. Can you please check I change code correct?

Comment: You first need to put **`$websites = $block->getAllWebsites();`** in **`<?php ?>`** tags.

Comment: Can you please check update2? 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: @Sylvester, updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Ok Mohit thank you, but last question. How to name this block xml and where I should put this? (in which folder) ?

Comment: @Sylvester, please see my update.

Comment: Mohit, I change default.xml and this line. But after upload still issue with  foreach() :( (update3)

Comment: You need to replace Your\Custom\Block\Class with your own block class, which you have created.

Comment: Please explain about what block do we need to create ? Do we need to override switcher.php block of vendor?

Comment: @chanchal, you need to create a block file in your custom module **app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/Block/[ClassName].php** and write the code mentioned above under **Update** heading in my answer.

Comment: I am created custom theme inherit from blank theme, how to enable switcher?

Comment: Have you enabled multiple languages?

Answer (score 0):

Because now you have one store view for a particular website.

language switcher when one website has multiple store view.

Comment: Yes Dear I know this : ) But how to set switcher for multiple website? That's why I ask

Comment: For website switcher?

Comment: Sweety, issues solved