# How to setup multi-language store in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I need to setup multi-language options for multiple websites in Magento2.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article on this. Please refer
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-administration/create-multi-language-store-magento-2-part-2/

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried doing this way but its not being displayed in the frontend.

Comment: Are you trying on Luma theme ? try appending `?___store=fr` to you store URL. Here `fr` is Store View Code you setted up in Admin while creating new View.

Comment: yea am working luma, localhost

Comment: Did you try appending the `?___store=fr` to your store URL. If still it doesn't then try running the command `bin/magento cache:clean` &  `bin/magento cache:flush`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer you should see a language switcher. But will only work if you've got multiple languages on a single website. Are you seeing the language switcher?

More details here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251986/70343

Comment: no i need for multiple websites